# Add data types ERD

Tags: uml, erd, navision, visual-paradigm

I want to add or change data-types of an ERD in Visual Paradigm, because I want to make an ERD with the datatypes that are being used in Microsoft Dynamics Navision 2009.
I can add a new language for the whole project, but this won't work in ERD's.
How can I use the Navision datatypes in Visual Paradigm 2014?

Comment: I'm not a Visual Paradigm user but according to http://www.visual-paradigm.com/tutorials/erd.jsp step 7 it seems that you can enter **any** data type as free-form text. It should be enough as long as you are not going to generate some DDL code from the ERD. Is anything wrong with this approach?

Comment: No it isn't realy free-form text. When you enter another not-UML datatype, it will return to the default value integer(10)